# How to create a custom Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, kernel, software-installation

Can any one tell me the easiest way to create a system with live cd with installing function. Which can install backtrack all tools??
I need to create a custom boot animation and everything!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SUSE Studio](https://susestudio.com/). It basically lets you choose a base and customize it, appearance-wise and package-wise.

Comment: But how to install backtrack packages to it.

Comment: I thought Backtrack was an OS...I'm a little confused on what you're trying to do...why is just using Backtrack not an option?

Comment: Yeah but we can install tools any way like kali n we van install those apps on ubuntu too.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Have you searched for the specific packages on SUSE Studio?

Comment: If they're not there, you can upload RPMs of them if you can find them online...

Comment: For suse i dont think they are available i tried that few months ago

Comment: I would try again, just in case. If it's still a no-go, see if you can find RPM's online -- you can upload them within SUSE Studio

Comment: Also, do you have a list of the _specific_ packages you need? If you do, I would add that to your question...

Comment: Ok. I will add them. Also ill give it another shot as you said.